# s3 javascript createMultipartUpload

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

How can we initiate createMultipartUpload ? This is the link & code;
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createMultipartUpload-property

```
var params = {
  Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Key: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  ACL: 'private | public-read | public-read-write | authenticated-read | bucket-owner-read | bucket-owner-full-control',
  CacheControl: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ContentDisposition: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ContentEncoding: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ContentLanguage: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ContentType: 'STRING_VALUE',
  Expires: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789,
  GrantFullControl: 'STRING_VALUE',
  GrantRead: 'STRING_VALUE',
  GrantReadACP: 'STRING_VALUE',
  GrantWriteACP: 'STRING_VALUE',
  Metadata: {
    someKey: 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* anotherKey: ... */
  },
  RequestPayer: 'requester',
  SSECustomerAlgorithm: 'STRING_VALUE',
  SSECustomerKey: new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE',
  SSECustomerKeyMD5: 'STRING_VALUE',
  SSEKMSKeyId: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256 | aws:kms',
  StorageClass: 'STANDARD | REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
  WebsiteRedirectLocation: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
s3.createMultipartUpload(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Configuring just that codes above doesnt work. We need some another property to setup some extra codes I guess. But how ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY /* Specify your Access key */,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY /* Specify your Secret Access key */
});

var params = {
  Bucket: "..." /* Specify your Bucket name */, 
  Key: "test.zip" /* Specify the file name */
 };

s3.createMultipartUpload(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) 
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     
       console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

You have to specify 4 parameters to make the code work: your Access Key, your Secret access key, your bucket name and the file name.

Answer (score -3):

```
 $source = '/path/to/large/file.zip';
$uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3Client, $source, [
    'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
    'key'    => 'my-file.zip',
]);

do {
    try {
        $result = $uploader->upload();
    } catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
        $uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3Client, $source, [
            'state' => $e->getState(),
        ]);
    }
} while (!isset($result));
```

You can use Multipart Uploader.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-multipart-upload.html?highlight=multipartupload

Comment: He is asking about Javascript... not php